# How to call data from a relationship of two models

Tags: laravel-5

I have two basic tables models:

User

- id
- id_number
- email

Address

- id
- user_id
- zip_code

My current User Model:

```
public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}
```

My current Address Model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

I am trying to show the zip code of a user to the blade view

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="id_number">Id Number</label>
    <input name="id_number" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->id_number }}" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->email }}" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="zip_code">Zip Code</label>
    <input name="zip_code" type="number" class="form-control" id="" value="{{ $user->addresses()->zip_code }}">
</div>
```

Only the Id Number and E-mail seems to show data properly, I can't seem to make the zip_code show its data: `value="{{ $user->addresses()->zip_code }}"`

Am I missing anything?

**EDIT**:

My controller by the way:

```
$users = User::where('deleted_at', '=', NULL)->paginate(5);
return view('member.home')->with(compact('users'));
```

A good friend of mine suggested to do something like this:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($users->addresses()->get() as $address)
        {{ $address->zip_code }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And it works just fine. It will be highly appreciated if anyone can provide other methods for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your relation in address is `belongsTo`:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then in your loop no need to run a query on the addresses, just call them as property on the user:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->addresses as $address)
        {{ $address->zip_code }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And this will make multiple queries for each user, so you would want to eager load the addresses like this in your controller:

```
$users = User::with('addresses')->get();
```

Comment: This explains a lot of questions I have. Great and if I may ask, since I am loading data from the user table still (like email), is the best method is to do the nested foreach that you have posted?

by the way, my controller goes like this:
    `public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('deleted_at', '=', NULL)->paginate(5);

        return view('member.home')->with(compact('users'));
    }`

Comment: @JustinF yeah, don't think there is anything wrong with the nested loop. Your controller can be like this `$users = User::with('addresses')->where('deleted_at', '=', NULL)->paginate(5);`.

Comment: And if `deleted_at` is part of the laravel soft deletes, then no need for this where clause.

Comment: I added this answer as the answer. Well explained. Yes, my deleted_at is declared as softdeletes. Because I want to make sure the the only users shown are those that have NULL in the deleted_at, im not sure if im doing the best way for that part.

Comment: Yeah, laravel does that by default, so no need to add your own where clause. You could check the SQL logs to make sure or a debug bar if you're using any.